# Rails 3.1 coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I have this weird failing coffeescript, [from this demo](https://github.com/ernie/ransack_demo). The demo code works fine on my local machine. And I've blatantly copied it, wholesale, into my own rails 3.1 app. There are no useful error messages but the buttons are acting as if they're buttons which don't know they have a script attached to them - they're refreshing the page.

app/assets/application.js contains the compiled coffee script.
The compiled html is identical between the two apps. 
Other javascripts are working. 
I've deleted all css and javascript except this one, and it's not working. 
The coffeescript is fine as it's working on the demo app on my machine.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious about how you use coffee script in the asset pipeline?

Code:

application.rb:

```
   # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true
```

Search.js.coffee:

```
class @Search
  constructor: (@templates = {}) ->

  remove_fields: (button) ->
    $(button).closest('.fields').remove()

  add_fields: (button, type, content) ->
    new_id = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp('new_' + type, 'g')
    $(button).before(content.replace(regexp, new_id))

  nest_fields: (button, type) ->
    new_id = new Date().getTime()
    id_regexp = new RegExp('new_' + type, 'g')
    template = @templates[type]
    object_name = $(button).closest('.fields').attr('data-object-name')
    sanitized_object_name = object_name.replace(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/g, '_').replace(/_$/, '')
    template = template.replace(/new_object_name\[/g, object_name + "[")
    template = template.replace(/new_object_name_/, sanitized_object_name + '_')
    $(button).before(template.replace(id_regexp, new_id))
```

Application helper:

```
 def setup_search_form(builder)
      fields = builder.grouping_fields builder.object.new_grouping, object_name: 'new_object_name', child_index: "new_grouping" do |f|
        render('grouping_fields', f: f)
      end
      content_for :document_ready, %Q{
        var search = new Search({grouping: "#{escape_javascript(fields)}"});
        $('button.add_fields').live('click', function() {
          search.add_fields(this, $(this).data('fieldType'), $(this).data('content'));
          return false;
        });
        $('button.remove_fields').live('click', function() {
          search.remove_fields(this);
          return false;
        });
        $('button.nest_fields').live('click', function() {
          search.nest_fields(this, $(this).data('fieldType'));
          return false;
        });
      }.html_safe
    end

    def button_to_remove_fields(name, f)
      content_tag :button, name, class: 'remove_fields'
    end

    def button_to_add_fields(name, f, type)
      new_object = f.object.send "build_#{type}"
      fields = f.send("#{type}_fields", new_object, child_index: "new_#{type}") do |builder|
        render(type.to_s + "_fields", f: builder)
      end
      content_tag :button, name, :class => 'add_fields', 'data-field-type' => type, 'data-content' => "#{fields}"
    end

    def button_to_nest_fields(name, type)
      content_tag :button, name, :class => 'nest_fields', 'data-field-type' => type
    end
```

advanced_search.html.erb

```
<h1>Advanced ISBN Search</h1>
<%= link_to 'Simple mode', isbns_path %>

<%= search_form_for @search, url: advanced_search_isbns_path, html: {method: :post} do |f| %>
  <% setup_search_form f %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sorting</legend>
    <%= f.sort_fields do |s| %>
      <%= render 'sort_fields', f: s %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to_add_fields "Add Sort", f, :sort %>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Condition Groups</legend>
    <%= f.grouping_fields do |g| %>
      <%= render 'grouping_fields', f: g %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to_add_fields "Add Condition Group", f, :grouping %>
  </fieldset>

  <%= label_tag :distinct, 'Return distinct records?' %>
  <%= check_box_tag :distinct, '1', params[:distinct].to_i == 1 %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'results' %>
```

Example partial: _grouping_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset class="fields" data-object-name="<%= f.object_name %>">
  <legend>Match <%= f.combinator_select %> conditions <%= button_to_remove_fields "remove", f %></legend>
  <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
    <%= render 'condition_fields', f: c %>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to_add_fields "Add Condition", f, :condition %>

  <%= f.grouping_fields do |g| %>
    <%= render 'grouping_fields', f: g %>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_to_nest_fields "Add Condition Group", :grouping %>
</fieldset>
```

Update / solution.

Firebug pointed out that there's a conflict with some other js, in the Cocoon gem. Here's its code:

```
 $('.add_fields').live('click', function() {
    var assoc   = $(this).attr('data-association');
    var assocs  = $(this).attr('data-associations');
    var content = $(this).attr('data-template');
    var insertionPosition = $(this).attr('data-association-insertion-position');
    var insertionNode = $(this).attr('data-association-insertion-node');
    var insertionCallback = $(this).data('insertion-callback');
    var regexp_braced = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assoc + '\\]', 'g');
    var regexp_underscord = new RegExp('_new_' + assoc + '_', 'g');
    var new_id  = new Date().getTime();
    var newcontent_braced = '[' + new_id + ']';
    var newcontent_underscord = '_' + new_id + '_';
    var new_content = content.replace(regexp_braced, '[' + new_id + ']');
    if (new_content == content) {
        regexp_braced = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assocs + '\\]', 'g');
        regexp_underscord = new RegExp('_new_' + assocs + '_', 'g');
        new_content = content.replace(regexp_braced, '[' + new_id + ']');
    }
    new_content = new_content.replace(regexp_underscord, newcontent_underscord);

    if (insertionNode) {
      insertionNode = $(insertionNode);
    }
    else {
      insertionNode = $(this).parent();
    }

    var contentNode = $(new_content);

    if (insertionPosition == 'after'){
      insertionNode.after(contentNode);
    } else {
      insertionNode.before(contentNode); 
    }

    if(insertionCallback){
      insertionCallback.call(contentNode);
    }

    return false;
  });
```

The conflicting line is

```
var new_content = content.replace(regexp_braced, '[' + new_id + ']');
```

Renaming add_fields to add_s_fields in application_helper and the coffeescript sorted it out.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. Will do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inject some JS code with

```
content_for :document_ready %Q{ ... }
```

but I don't see the requisite

```
<%= content_for :document_ready %>
```

in your ERB markup. Can you verify that the JS code is on the page? If so, where is it—are you sure it's being run after `class @Search` is defined?

Comment: Aha - getting closer. This is in layouts/pplication.html.erb - code not working yet but I bet that's the cause. Will investigate more - thank you. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>RansackDemo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      <%= yield :document_ready %>
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Accepting this answer as it was one of the problems. The conflict with the Cocoon gem was the other issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `class @Search` is suspicious to me. What happens if you get rid of the `@`?

Comment: Thanks for the thought - after a server restart, same deal, though, the browser refreshes. The trace reads:

cache: [POST /isbns/advanced_search] invalidate, pass


Started POST "/isbns/advanced_search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-01 22:54:48 +0100
  Processing by IsbnsController#advanced_search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RLsL68UmMIZZGxL/8JdJY3GR3coVSn32i9RMLOpamjU=", "q"=>{"g"=>{"0"=>{"m"=>"and"}}}}

Comment: @Michael That's a perfectly valid way of attaching `class Search` to `this`, which (in that scope) is `window`. Without the `@`, `class Search` would only be visible within `Search.js.coffee`; with it, it's a global.